# Ensuring Text over portfolio images appear only in designated li and not in all li's at the same time

Tags: jquery, image, text, hover

I have been trying to figure out how to ensure text only appears in one box using jquery when I run over a portfolio picture of the li, versus appearing in every single box concurrently.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
<ul class="box">
<li class="titulo"><p>Graphic Design</p></li>
<li><a class="zoom" rel="graphic" href="#"><div class="subname">example</div><img class="hover" src="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="zoom" rel="graphic" href="#"> <div class="subname">example</div><img class="hover" src="#"></a></li>
<li><a class="zoom" rel="graphic" href="#"><div class="subname">example</div> <img class="hover" src="#"></a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.subname').hide();
$('.box li').mouseover(function() {
$('.subname').show();
}); 
$('.box li').mouseout(function() {
$('.subname').hide();
});

}); 
</script>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the "this" selector. 
The "this" selector, allows you to refer to the exact element that triggered your event. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.subname').hide();
    $('.box li').mouseover(function() {
        $('.subname', this).show();
    }); 
    $('.box li').mouseout(function() {
        $('.subname', this).hide();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

A shorter version of your code:

```
$('.box li').hover(function() {
    $('.subname', this).show();
}, function() {
    $('.subname', this).hide();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not a problem. Don't forget to mark as the answer please. Thanks!   :)